# How to make a chart with rows based on cell value?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to make a chart (or a column in my case) that would fill in a certain number of rows based on a cell value.

For example, in my file I have:

```
Alex  5
Josh  3
```

Normally I would be doing this manually but what I want as output is the following (and this can be the same worksheet doesn't matter):

```
Alex  Date
Alex  Date
Alex  Date
Alex  Date
Alex  Date
Josh  Date
Josh  Date
Josh  Date
```

Where the value next to a name determines how many times that person's name shows up in the chart/column, followed by the next person's name with the number of times based on the value next to the name. Date would just be "today's date" or whatever date I happened to be working on this sheet. Ideally, this would just happen automatically. Possible without a macro? I can also try a macro for this, but I have zero experience with that.

Comment: When you add the *Excel* tag, it is not necessary to redundantly repeat the name in your title or body text. The tag tells everyone the question is about Excel, and the needless repetition is just noise. The tag system works extremely well here and doesn't need any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following formula in every cell of a new column (in the same table):

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$8;A2)
```

This won't give you a new table, just an expansion of the existing table.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Use this in a NEW column, but in the same table. I don't start of with a table just one column. So would I use this next to the cells? If ```Josh 5``` took up A1 and A2, I would run this in A3?

Comment: You could do it by typing a name in cell A1, a date in cell B1 and then the formula in cell C1. And so on in A2, B2 and C2.  
The formula $A$1:$A$8 should be adjusted to the range in column A you have all your names in.

Comment: But I need to include the number next to the name within the formula. I guess there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: You could place the formula in the cell next to the names as well. And then you could place the date after the formula-cell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more according to your wish:
Make one worksheet with the following info

[image]

Then make another worksheet with the following info (you should type the formula in column B cells `=COUNTIF(Worksheet1!$A$1:$A$6;A1)`.)
[image]

It also can be another number of cells on the same worksheet.